# How to change the serviceConfig of a service defined in nixpkgs from configuration.nix?

Tags: nixos, nixpkgs

The nagios in nixpkgs has `systemd.services.nagios.serviceConfig.Restart="always";` which is cluttering the `journalctl -u nagios` log and should be Restart="no"; instead!

## MySQL fix

For MySQL this works:

```
systemd.services.mysql.serviceConfig = {
  Restart = "always";
  RestartSec="10s";
  StartLimitInterval="1min";
};
```

Since the MySQL service does not list any of the 'Restart', 'RestartSec', or 'StartLimitInterval' I suppose.

## Attempted nagios fix

Using the same mechanism for nagios as for MySQL before, I try:

```
systemd.services.nagios.serviceConfig.Restart = "no";
```

Gives me a:

```
error: The option `systemd.services.nagios.serviceConfigRestart' defined in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix' does not exist.
(use ‘--show-trace’ to show detailed location information)
```

If I updated it to:

```
systemd.services.nagios.serviceConfig = lib.mkForce { Restart = "no"; };
```

The result is that the values in `systemd.services.mysql.serviceConfig` are now only containing 'Restart' but lack the important 'ExecStart' and other service definitions:

```
journalctl -u nagios
nagios.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
```

Finally using this:

```
systemd.services.nagios.serviceConfig = config.systemd.services.nagios.serviceConfig // { Restart = "no"; };
```

Give me a:

```
nixos-rebuild switch
error: infinite recursion encountered, at /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/nixpkgs/lib/attrsets.nix:199:44
(use ‘--show-trace’ to show detailed location information)
```

Answer (score 1):

> `systemd.services.nagios.serviceConfig.Restart = "no";`

- should work

> error: The option `systemd.services.nagios.serviceConfigRestart' 
>   defined in`/etc/nixos/configuration.nix' does not exist.
>   (use ‘--show-trace’ to show detailed location information)

- Suggests that you just accidentally omitted the `.` in `serviceConfig.Restart`

Some further explanation in case of it's of any use:

> systemd.services.nagios.serviceConfig = lib.mkForce { Restart = "no";
>   }; the result is that the values in
>   systemd.services.mysql.serviceConfig are now only containing 'Restart'
>   but lack the important 'ExecStart' and other service definitions:
>
> journalctl -u nagios nagios.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and
>   ExecStop= setting. Refusing.

- Is because you've forced replacement of `serviceConfig`

> finally using this:
>
> systemd.services.nagios.serviceConfig =
>   config.systemd.services.nagios.serviceConfig // { Restart = "no"; };
>   give me a:
>
> nixos-rebuild switch error: infinite recursion encountered, at
>   /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/nixpkgs/lib/attrsets.nix:199:44

- Is because you're defining the value of `serviceConfig` to be the value of `serviceConfig`, which is an infinite recursion!

Answer (score 1):

turns out, this had been a bug in nixpkgs, see https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/41446